# How to obtain the generated keys when using the NamedParameterJDBCTemplate in a batchUpdate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to understand how to perform a batch insert statement (for speed improvement) and obtain the created primary key values for the newly created records.

I have seen the KeyHolder interface, but there seems to be no function that combines it with a batch update only a single update (which I want to avoid for performance reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible by extending JdbcTemplate and adding a method which is an exact copy of batchUpdate method and take an extra param of Type KeyHolder, there in PreparedStatementCallback  after ps.executeBatch() you should call                     ResultSet keys = ps.getGeneratedKeys() and extract the generated keys and store theme in KeyHolder but there is no guarantee that ps.getGeneratedKeys()  will return value it depends on database

Comment: Hello biiyamn, thanks for your response. Can you explain why this would not work on all databases?

Comment: in some database , returning auto generated keys after batch insert is not possible making this feature not available in the driver. Even, if the database supports this feature it might not be available in the driver because this feature is optional in jdbc spec

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like it's an uncertain and not portable way to proceed. I guess I need to rethink the problem/solution a bit.